# If dim specifies the quantity of data in an array, wouldn't using dim - 1 potentially cause me to lose an element?

Tags: arrays, c

I'm currently working on manipulating arrays in C, and I'm a bit confused about why dim - 1 is commonly used in array-related operations. If dim specifies the quantity of data in an array, wouldn't using dim - 1 potentially cause me to lose an element?

For example, in the context of the Bubble Sort algorithm, it is common to use:
`for (int i = 0; i < dim - 1; i++)`.
Is there a specific reason for this convention?
Do I lose an element by initializing the index at 1 or setting it to dim - 1?

I tried without this convention, and it seemed to work the same, but it's marked as incorrect.

Comment: It depends very specifically on the actual code, but one common reason is that somewhere inside the loop a reference is made to elements at indices i *and* i+1.

Comment: If you want to look at all the characters in a string, then if `dim` is `sizeof(string)` with a null terminator byte, using `dim - 1` as the upper bound of the lop avoids processing the null byte at the end of the array.  OTOH, if `dim` is `strlen(string)`, then using `dim-1` does not check the last character of the string and would invoke undefined behaviour if the string is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. Usual loops that do or check something for each element of a size `dim` array are usually programmed as `for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)` which gets  you one iteration each and values for `i` suitable to address each array element. (Of course 0-based, i.e. starting with index 0.)

But many algorithms, notably the bubble sort which was mentioned in the question title at one point, look at each possible pair of neighboring elements. That is, you look at each `i` and at `i+1` as indexes as you step through the whole array. But doing that, you need to stop BEFORE the last usually available `i` (being `dim-1`), because you cannot use `dim -1 +1` for the other part of the last pair. So the last pair is `dim-2` and `dim-1`.

A loop that will allow you in each iteration to access `i` and `i+1` and end up using `dim-2` and `dim-1` is:

`for (int i = 0; i < dim - 1; i++)`

So that is why.

*(This is very close to a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77851996/if-dim-specifies-the-quantity-of-data-in-an-array-wouldnt-using-dim-1-potent#comment137248189_77851996) by [President James K. Polk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238704/president-james-k-polk), but I think turning a comment into an answer is OK and that I substantially extend it. Also, I typed before realising the presence of that comment, but that is probably less of an excuse... :-) )*